# ld: framework not found Alamofire 5.0

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I've spent few days trying to solve this issue and I am running out of ideas now.

I have:

Xcode v11.3.1

Apple Swift version 5

cocoapods-1.9.1

I am creating an Xcode project with a Tab Bar view with some other ViewControllers.

After pod init in root project path I am editing my Podfile as below:
[image]

now when I try to build my app I am getting build error, as per below:
[image]

I tried to edit Framework, clean my project, reopen Xcode, try fresh copy, upgrade Alamfire to the newest version but nothing works.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: When using pods, make sure you open the Xcode workspace, not the project.

Comment: I have open the Xcode workspace.

But when I try to run my app, I have this error:

Framework not found Alamofire....?

Comment: Did you run the pod install command?

Comment: Yes I run that commend in my project folder. My Podfile stay in the same directory where the .xcworkspace and the xcodeproj files stays (/project). Is that correct? My other .swift files stays in a other folder. (/project/project/...)